# Can't read relative text files from java applet on server

Tags: java, file, applet

I have made a game in java in the form of an applet. It contains two text files:

dictionary.txt - contains all accepted words in the game (similar to boggle)

highScores.txt - contains the high scores of anyone who plays the game online

Everything works perfectly in eclipse, but when I put the applet on my website, wrapped in html the way all my other applets work in, it gives me an AccessControlException and says I can't access the dictionary text file. I am sick and tired of researching this. Almost everything says to sign my applet, but I don't want to pay hundreds of dollars and I'm pretty sure there's a better way. Some places mention policytool to make a policy file, but it's really confusing how they explain it. I have tried putting the text files inside the jar, and outside, in the same folder. Someone please help me figure this out.

Here's how I load my files:

```
    try{
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/dictionary.txt"));
        boolean endLoop = false;
        while(!endLoop){
            String s = b.readLine();
            if(s != null){ dictionary.add(s); }
            else{ endLoop = true; }
        }
        b.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Applets are excuted client sided. Are these txt files in the server? then you should read them using a remote call. But we should see the code to make sure why. The restriction may be that you are trying to read a file locally but the clieant needs to provide permissions to the applets for that.

Answer (score 2):

When the applet runs inside a web browser, the two files are still on the web server. So you cannot access them via file system - even if you had the permission to do so, because they are simply not there!

```
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res/dictionary.txt"));
```

Tries to access the local (i.e. on the users computer that runs the browser) file *"/res/dictionary.txt"*.

There are two possible solutions to this problem

1. Put the files somewhere on your webserver and open a `URLConnection` to read them. This is always allowed (an applet can connect to the server it originates from).
2. Put the files into your .jar file and access them using the applets `ClassLoader`.

Example for solution 2 (if path is relative to the root directory of the jar):

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("res/dictionary.txt");
```

or (if path is relative to the directory of the class file):

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/dictionary.txt");
```

Comment: I am inexperienced with servers in java. And besides, it finds the files, the error is that I don't have permission.

Comment: How do you know? Permissions are checked before the file is accessed.

Comment: When the text files are in the jar file it still doesn't work. It can load PNG files, just not text files for some reason

Comment: How do you try to load the files? Please add some code to your question!

Comment: *"And besides, it finds the files"*  It won't once the server and client are on *different machines*.  As mentioned in the answer, resources on the server (or in the class-path) can be accessed by URL.  They cannot be accessed by `File` unless the `File` is supplied by the client, and the applet is trusted.